# How do i enable this code of mine to accept multiple selections and also display result using them?

Tags: php, mysql, html

So this is my form (checkbox that allows multiple selections)

```
echo"Please select questions to analyze : ";
$qsq = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT question_text FROM questions ");
echo "<form name='whatever' action='next.php' method='GET'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsq))
{

 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';

}

echo"<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' /></form>";
```

And this is another php file that generate results from the page above.

```
$yes=mysql_query("select lo_category, count(*) from questions where question_text='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["choice"]) . "' group by lo_category order by lo_category");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($yes)) {
    echo '<b>Category :</b> ' . $row['lo_category'] . ',' . $row['count(*)'] . '<br />'; 
}
```

I got the result but it's only for the last choice in the checkboxes which means showing only result from 1 choice but actually i have selected a few from the checkbox.Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use choice[] for your input name. This way, you'll have an array to use in your php code.

```
... type="checkbox" name="choice[]" ...
```

Of course, you'll have to change the sql query to handle this.

```
... where question_text IN ('" . implode("', '", $_GET["choice"]) . "')
```

(untested!)

On a side note, I would really urge you to use prepared statements for your db stuff,
see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

All of your checkboxes have the same name. You need to give each a different one.
Bad example:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsq))
{
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="choice[' . $i++ . ']" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';
}
```

Edit: If I remember correctly, if you include the brackets ([]), your PHP code will give you an array named choice with the results of your choices.

Comment: you mean this `<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="' . $row["question_text"] . '" /> ' . $row["question_text"] . '<br />';
` the choice ? How can i make it dynamically generated ? Can u show me please...

Comment: Bad example, because it's not complete and doesn't tell you anything about handling the result from the form submit.

Comment: so i have to edit the one in query too right ? how should i put it ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `$_GET["choice"]` will return an array of your results, not a String. So you need to iterate over it. But I think, you should simply try it and see what you get.